# Python script runs independently, but when called by flask app, throws permission error

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app running on Ubuntu that calls a separate python script. Within my Flask App, this is what calls the script:

```
args = ['python3', '/home/make_videos/code/master_script_slim.py', 'videos', '0,1', '01', '01']
output = subprocess.call(args)
```

When I run this, I get this error in the apache.log:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/make_videos/code/master_script_slim.py", line 90, in <module>
    make_dirs()
  File "/home/make_videos/code/master_script_slim.py", line 81, in make_dirs
    os.makedirs(sequence_creation_temp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 231, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 231, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/make_videos/ASV_Tests/01'
```

But, when I run this script (`master_script_slim.py`) manually both in and out of my venv, I do not get this error.

Clearly it's a permissions issue while creating a series of directorys, but I can't exactly figure out how to fix it. I tried using `sys.executable` to work around the permissions, but the Flask app is python2, and I need to specifically call python3 for this script.

Here is the makedirs portion of the code that is bombing out:

```
sequence_creation_temp = working_root_path + '/' + artist_id + '/' + art_id + '/temp/'

thumbnails_final = working_root_path + '/' + artist_id + '/' + art_id + '/animated_thumbnails/'
thumbnails_image = working_root_path + '/' + artist_id + '/' + art_id + '/image_thumbnail/'
videos_final = working_root_path + '/' + artist_id + '/' + art_id + '/videos/'
scripts_final = working_root_path + '/' + artist_id + '/' + art_id + '/scripts/'

def make_dirs():
    if not os.path.exists(sequence_creation_temp):
        os.makedirs(sequence_creation_temp)
    if not os.path.exists(thumbnails_final):
        os.makedirs(thumbnails_final)
    if not os.path.exists(videos_final):
        os.makedirs(videos_final)
    if not os.path.exists(scripts_final):
        os.makedirs(scripts_final)
    if not os.path.exists(thumbnails_image):
        os.makedirs(thumbnails_image)
make_dirs()
```

Comment: apache mostly works as user `wwwdata` which has different  privilages and uses different environment - it can has different variables. it protects system against hackers.

Comment: that makes sense. so should maybe I should move these scripts/folders somewhere inside /var/www/FlaskApp?

Comment: probably it could be the best solution. Some people add `root` (or `sudo`) privilages to `wwwdata` but it can be the worst solution :)

Answer (score 1):

furas provideded great info. I changed the script so python was creating the directories WITHIN the flask app, and everything went off without a hitch.